# Word for "speeding up a process" in line with the idiom "to kick-start"

Tags: idioms, synonyms, metaphors

I am not a native English speaker but I'm looking for **a good word that highlights that a process is improved in that it completes more quickly**. I thought there was a word that is semantically in the same field as "to kick-start" (referring to a motorcycle), but for the life of me I can't find anything in dictionaries or thesauri. Does a word like that exist? If not, any other word with a metaphorical reference?

Side note: I'll be using this word as part of a title for an article, probably as a gerund. E.g. "Kick-starting My Project" (obviously not with those words).

Comment: *to speed up* ***Is*** the analogous phrase.

Comment: You may be looking for the word "Expedite" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a process is improved in such a way that it takes less time to complete, the process is said to have been *streamlined*.

> The film director found that re-creating the difficult-to-film sequence on a soundstage streamlined the process of completing the film by saving six days of shooting.

Shooting a film on a soundstage, I am told, has many advantages over shooting a scene on the streets of Paris, for example. As long as realism is not sacrificed, the savings in time and money can be substantial.

Comment: Also a metaphor based on vehicular transportation.

Comment: Streamlining is more about making something faster by making it more efficient, rather than speeding up through extra effort. Of course that could be the desired metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

***kick/shift/push/send (something) into overdrive*** [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22the+process+into+overdrive%22&biw=589&bih=386&noj=1&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwgZTItLHJAhUCOhQKHbo2CjAQ_AUIDCgG)

> into overdrive: into a condition of hard work and effectiveness.
> *There are times when you think this show is going to shift into overdrive, but it never does.* [Cambridge Dictionary of American
> Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/overdrive)

***step up***

> 1. to make something more active. *I hope we can step the pace of business up in the next few days. We can step up business considerably by putting out a larger sign.*
> 2. to make something go or run faster. *The engineer stepped the motors up and the production line moved even faster. Please step up the speed of your activity.* [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/step+up)

***move/step up a gear***

> to start to work or play more effectively or quickly than before *With
> just five lengths to go, the German swimmer stepped up a gear and
> edged ahead to win the race*. [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/step+up+a+gear)

***step on the gas***

> : to hurry in order to get something done quickly; **step on it** *If we're going to get this done today, it's time to step on the gas.*
> Etymology: based on the literal meaning of step on the gas (to make a car go faster by giving the engine more gas)
> [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/step+on+the+gas)

***drop the hammer***

> (Expression) American English Idiom: to bring a pending act to
> fruition. Usually connotes an act which will have serious
> consequences. Also used in reference to quickly increasing speed in a
> car by manipulating a manual transmission gear shift (the hammer). [Dictionary Of by Farlex](http://www.definition-of.com/drop+the+hammer)

***(put) the pedal on the metal***

> : to make something go forward or increase as fast as possible : *Ingrid
> put the pedal to the metal and finished writing her essay a day early.*
> Etymology: based on the idea of pressing a car's gas pedal (a flat
> piece that you control with your foot) all the way to the floor to
> make the car go as fast as possible. [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Pedal)

***shift to full throttle*** [Google Pictures](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=1024&bih=672&noj=1&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=CXpYVtzRM8S2af66hZAJ&q=motorcycle+throttle&oq=motorcycle+throttle&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.0i19l5.5584.12274.0.13550.18.17.0.1.1.0.2305.7542.0j10j3j7-1j1j1.16.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..10.8.2602.eV0m473kSl0)

> The definition of full throttle is doing something at full speed.
> An example of full throttle is a runner racing with his optimal energy and speed. [Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/full-throttle#SGLlG0e3mX3QLAA2.99)

Answer (score 1):

**shift to high gear**

[LINK](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/high+gear)

> **high gear**
>   ...
>   2. *Informal* A state of maximum activity, energy, or force: Her mind was in high gear during the debate competition.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of *jump-start*? From [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump-start):

> 2a :  to start or restart rapidly or forcefully
>   2b :  to impart fresh or renewed energy to

It really isn't used to mean *"to complete more quickly"* but to mean *"to get something moving again after it has slowed or stalled"*. It's based metaphorically on the fact that if a car is stalled because of a dead battery<sup>1</sup>, you can jump-start it to get it moving again.

<sup>1</sup> This doesn't happen to cars anywhere near as often as it used to.

Comment: Yes, it is common to hear of "jump starting" a project, even a new project.  Even thought the idiom's implication that the project initially had a "dead battery" would be rather pejorative if taken literally, the idiom is not regarded as reflecting negatively on the project's current /prior state, but simply implies getting things suddenly moving.

Answer (score 1):

How about stimulate?

**[Stimulate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stimulate)**

> raise levels of physiological or nervous activity in (the body or any biological system).
>
> encourage development of or increased activity in (a state or process).

**[Catalysis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catalysis)**

Verb: catalyse

> *Chemistry.* the causing or accelerating of a chemical change by the addition of a catalyst.

Related idiom:

**[Put the pedal to the metal](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+pedal+to+the+metal)**

> to make something go forward or increase as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

[*accelerate*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=accelerate):

1. Move faster.
   "The car accelerated"; - speed up, speed, quicken
2. **Cause to move faster**.
   "He accelerated the car"; - speed, speed up
3. Cause to occur rapidly - induce, stimulate, rush, hasten, speed up

Comment: Yes, this seems the most fitting to me.  To bring to completion sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may convey the idea saying that ***the process has been [enhanced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enhance)***:

***Enhance:***

> - (tr) to intensify or increase in quality, value, power, etc; improve; augment.

From *"Adopting the Rational Unified [Process](https://books.google.it/books?id=mKRQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22enhance%20a%20process%22&dq=%22enhance%20a%20process%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ_afS5bDJAhUGHQ8KHerbBWcQ6AEITDAG)*:"

> - ..in process engineering, the goal is *to develop or enhance a process model;* corresponds to a business use case in business engineering.

Answer (score 0):

The project may be realized **on a rush basis**.

Example: *if  a new client calls and needs a big project done on a rush basis, I quote at least 50% more than my regular rate and often refer to it as “time and a half” to put it in perspective*.

EDIT: **in a timeous manner** is another possibility that has not the negative connotation mentionned in your comment.

> "timeous" definition: In good time; sufficiently early
>
> Example: *ensure timeous completion and posting of applications*.

Comment: Unfortunately, to me it seems to have a negative connotation.

Comment: @BramVanroy - I edited my answer with another suggestion.